# Is this sentence grammatically and structurally correct?

Tags: sentence-structure, grammar-identification, comma, capitalization

The sentece is:

> Aus der Asche ganz allein,
>   steig ich auf zum Sonnenschein

I have doubts about the comma placement (or maybe a missing comma) and also about the capital letters.
Any other observations are also welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: These are 2 lines from the song "Hilf mir" by Rammstein. There is no comma in the original lyrics.

Comment: Yes indeed. And yes, there is no comma in the lyrics, that the reason why I'm asking, is that correct?

Comment: Welcome to GSE. Proofreading requests are off-topic. Please take the [tour](https://german.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the song, and poetry or lyrics can sometimes - intentionally, for the sake of rhyming or keeping verse meter - break rules of language, but under normal circumstances there should be no comma. That position, however, is obviously between the two lines, so there is a pause; someone not familiar with German listening to the song might therefore get the false impression that there was a comma.
The capitalization is also correct: in German the first word of a sentence and every noun are written with a capital letter - *Asche* (ash) and *Sonnenschein* (sunshine) are the only nouns in this sentence. Different from English, *ich* (I) is not capitalized in German.

Comment: Actually, I'm fairly certain that you could write "Aus der Asche, ganz allein, steig ich auf zum Sonnenschein", treating the "ganz allein" is an interjection to the rest of the sentence; but it would probably be clearer to use dashes - "Gedankenstriche" - instead of commas in that case.